# Stackoverflow widget for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget

[User Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) can be easily embed on wordpress. Is there any way to embed the stackoverflow widget in mobile app? Does `UIWebView` help me to achieve the result ?